# Tricky Limit Problem involving e

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Find $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\exp(-1/(x^2+y^2))$.

I've tried multiplying the power out by the conjugate, which gives me a power of $y^2-x^2/x^4-y^4$, but I still can't figure out how to whittle this down. The most confusing thing to me is that the answer is supposedly $0$. How can $e^\text{anything}$ limit to zero?

EDIT: I should add: I understand the general concept of what the graph looks like, and as the exponent shrinks, the number stretches towards infinity in the x direction. The issue is that I don't know how to actually formally solve this question other than a verbal explanation.

Comment: The limit of $(x,y)$ approaching _what_?

Comment: To your last question: $e^{-x}\to0$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty} e^x=0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You wrote things like $x^2$-$y^2$ rather than $x^2-y^2$, with a hyphen instead of a minus sign.  See my edits. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Oh, sorry, thanks Alex, it's the limit as x and y approach 0,0.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Think in terms of polar coordinates.  $x^2+y^2=r^2$, and use the hint given in the comment by Regret.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple if based on your comments you meant to say
$$
\lim_{(x,y) ->0} e^{\frac {- 1} {x^2 + y^2}} = e ^ { \lim_{(x,y)->0} \frac {- 1} {x^2 + y^2}}  = e^{-\lim_{(x, y)->0} \frac 1  {x^2+y^2}} = e^{-\infty} = 0
$$